# Get first day of the month will return correct date only on alert()

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, console.log

Hello guys I am quite confused while I am trying to to get the first day of the month and while trying to alert the first day it is showing me the following message:

`Sun Sep 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` but on console.log() like this `2019-08-31T23:00:00.000Z`

This is my code and I am trying to understand how can I get the first day of the month properly

```js
var dateD = new Date(), y = dateD.getFullYear(), m = dateD.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);

alert(firstDay) // Sun Sep 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
console.log(firstDay) // 2019-08-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Interesting! I don't see that happening, just tested this out in the `console`. Getting same values. `alert` doesn't change values apart from doing a `.toString()`. Can you make a snippet to reproduce that?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behavior in Chrome 77.0.3865.90. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see in the alert is the time in the local time zone. Your local time zone is BST (British Summer Time).

What you see in the console is the same date / time in UTC. You can see that because of the Z in the string. The Z means this is UTC.

So, both strings actually represent the same date/time, just in different time zones. And they do represent the first day of the month in your local timezone (BST).

---

When you use `console.log(firstDay)`, the Date object `firstDay` is sent to the console. And the environment that displays the value in the console chooses how to display the value. Your environment seems to choose to use `firstDay.toISOString()` or `firstDay.toJSON()` to display the value in the console.

If you want to enforce to see the same value in the console that the user would see, then convert the `Date` object to a string before passing it to `console.log` like this:

```
console.log("" + firstDay); // Force string conversion before logging
```

---

I can see the difference when executing this as an embedded code snippet on StackOverflow:

```js
var dateD = new Date(), y = dateD.getFullYear(), m = dateD.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);

alert(firstDay) 
console.log("Date object passed directly to log: ", firstDay)
console.log("Date object converted to string: " + firstDay)
```

Comment: Okay! @NineBerry but why is this happening, does alert changes something with representation?

Comment: This is likely because of your server time settings. You'll want to look into using UTC for timezone settings.

Comment: @NineBerry tested `alert` and `console.log` both on `chrome version 77.0.3865.90` browser itself.

Comment: @NineBerry I get it! But the fact that OP is using `alert` and `console.log` isn't environment has nothing to do with it because it would be browser itself. And it isn't reproducible on the browser.

Comment: @NineBerry NP. pretty curious about why this would be happening. And +1 to the explanation in the answer.

Comment: @ambianBeing See updated answer with embedded code snippet. This shows exactly this behaviour when executed directly from StackOverflow.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
var date = new Date();
var first = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var last = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Comment: this is not the problem he's asking why it's different format between ```console.log``` and ```alert```  when displaying the date